# CSS: 100% width table, with cells that have hidden overflow and irregular/minimal cell widths

Tags: css

I want a table:

- to remain in view without scrolling, if the length of the cells would make it too wide to display (the texts can be variable) .. so that is basic table/cell sizing behavior
- that does NOT wrap cell texts, but uses overflow instead (double lines make rows unequal in height and hard to read/scan)
- to keep cells that have narrow content (icon, date, etc) not to take up too much space, but need to take up just what they need (again: basic table behavior)

The problem:
The combination of **100% width table** and **table-layout:fixed** makes **each cell's width equal(!)**, which is not needed, some cells now take up useless white-space.

I'd not like to go into selectively having to set widths of cells that should be less wide for example.

Comment: This is impossible. We cannot add anything more.

Comment: I guess you will just have to swallow your pride and give each table cell a width in percents explicitly.

Comment: I re-entered the realm of HTML/CSS after some time. I was surprised by how much better CSS3 and HTML5 have become. I kind of hoped this was something I had missed .. :'(

Comment: not exactly the solution but one that works as a compromise is to define max widths based on the number of cells: http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/